# How dow I setup Archiva standalone to use Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, jetty, archiva

Ok, I'm struggling to get Archiva 1.4 in standalone mode to use an existing Postgres db.  Can anyone help me configure it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends if you are using standalone or in a servlet container

1)Standalone have a look here
http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.4-M4-SNAPSHOT/adminguide/standalone.html
replace com.mysql.jdbc.Driver with
your jdbc driver
and replace url jdbc:mysql://localhost/archiva

put your jdbc driver jar to lib directory
2) servlet container (it depends :-) )
for Apache Tomcat see
http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.4-M4-SNAPSHOT/adminguide/webapp.html
put your jdbc driver jar to lib directory
change values

driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"
           url="jdbc:derby:/path/to/database/users;create=true"

I have updated documentation [here database section](http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.4-M4-SNAPSHOT/adminguide/standalone.html)

Answer (score 1):

Working with Olivier, this was my final, working db config:

```
  <New id="users" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg>jdbc/users</Arg>
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource">
        <Set name="driverClassName">org.postgresql.Driver</Set>
        <Set name="url">jdbc:postgresql://<server>/Archiva</Set>
        <Set name="name">ArchivaApp</Set>
        <Set name="username">...</Set>
        <Set name="password">...</Set>
        <!-- depends on your concurrent users numbers -->
        <Set name="maxWait">10000</Set>
        <Set name="removeAbandonedTimeout">10000</Set>
        <Set name="maxActive">30</Set>
        <Set name="initialSize">15</Set>
        <Set name="removeAbandoned">true</Set>
        <Set name="logAbandoned">true</Set>
        <Set name="testOnBorrow">true</Set>
        <!-- very rigourous sql query validation -->
        <Set name="validationQuery">select 1</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </New>
```

It was important to set the testOnBorrow parameter; some of the others don't matter.